# Not getting any response using fetch()

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to send a http POST request using the JS fetch API, but I am not receiving any response, although the request goes through to the server and the data is posted as expected.

This is the code I am using in the frontend:

```js
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "id": "johndoe1234",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "card": "bhgst-xxxx",
        "permissions": 1
    })
}).then(resp => console.log(resp))
```

The error I am getting is as follows:
devtools screenshot:
[image: Devtool screnshot]

It works fine using Postman (And also using Python `requests`). This is the expected response (I get this same response using Postman).

```json
{
    "card": "bhgst-xxxx",
    "id": "johndoe1235",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "permissions": 1
}
```

Comment: `type: 'opaque'` - Is the browser console telling you about any CORS issues?

Comment: Without the `mode: no-cors` it does tell me about a CORS issue. But in the server the response header is set to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) to parse the body text as JSON.

```js
fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Assuming you meant `.then(json => console.log(json))` at the end there, no it doesn't help since the response body is `null` as shown in my devtools screenshot. Using this suggestion (with the correction) I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: @Denisovich `.then(console.log);` is exactly the same as `.then(json => console.log(json))` in this case. Now this appears to be an issue with your request not being allowed. Do you have CORS configured properly?

Comment: I have this in my server side code `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

Comment: @Denisovich You may also need to configure allowed methods and allowed headers.

Comment: I have solved the issue with some help, looks like the `no-cors` was causing all the problems setting the status to zero. It was indeed a CORS issue and I have taken care of it. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: If you have solved your problem, could you please post an answer yourself describing how you did it?